# How to read file from raw folder using sqlite?

Tags: android, file, android-sqlite

I have database audio file like this

id  audio

1   audio1

2   audio2

3   audio3

i have a listview that will call a row of data above based on id

and i have 3 audio file with name "audio1,audio2 and audio3" on "res/raw/" directory

i can play all of them if i just manually enter audio name like this

```
mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.audio1);
```

but what I want is to call audio file based on its id on database.

how to do that??
i tried a code like this

```
mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.cursor.getString(1));
```

but its a wrong code

Answer (score 1):

If you tried coding :-

```
Log.d("RAWAUDIOID","ID of raw audio file is " + String.valueOf(R.raw.audio1));
```

You would get a result such as :-

`08-03 22:07:44.926 1233-1233/pra.playrawaudio D/RAWAUDIOID: ID of raw audio file is` **`2131427328`**

That is `R.raw.audio1` is the ID (integer) given to the **R**esource when compiling the program (*not really accurate as they are generated before*). The ID will likely never be 1, 2 or 3 nor any number that you could reliably store in the DB and it would likely rarely if ever correlate to a generated **ID**.

Rather you should store the file name in the database and extract the file's id according to it's file name.

e.g.

```
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this,
            getResources().getIdentifier("audio1","raw",getPackageName()
            )
    );
```

Assuming that cursor (*as used in your code*) is valid and is appropriately positioned, and that all columns were selected using `SELECT * ....rest of the underlying query....` and thus that the column with offset **1** is the file name (e.g. the retrieved value could be **audio1**) then the above could be :-

```
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this,
            getResources().getIdentifier(
                    cursor.getString(1),
                    "raw",
                    getPackageName()
            )
    );
```

Comment: oh thanks sir :D. its work.

can I use 

"filename","raw",getPackageName() 

to replace any code that using (R.raw.filename) ?

Comment: @lulu that's good. Could you please tick the question as answered. re the question, yes, as long as filename is correct.